# Storing Rails app version in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cvs

Is storing version of Rails application in database is the right way ? Rails version it's a release production code version incremented every time we are doing deployment. It used for informational purposes only. Generally people recommended setting up version in `config/initializers/version.rb` but IMO it could be hard for change automatically during deployment (adding file to .gitignore or not and etc.) Using AR record we could easily had `ApplicationVersion.last.to_version in our code`. What do You thing about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about writing it out to a yaml file that you could generate during deployment?  It'd be a simple matter to generate that during deployment, especially if you're using a tool such as capistrano.

My concern about writing it to a file is that the production database isn't a concrete resource.  What if you have a crash and need to restore the database?  The database potentially will report a different version than the current state of the code.